# Vim Bind Shift Pageup to tabnext

Tags: vim, key-bindings

Why does

```
nnoremap <S-PageDown> :tabnext<CR>
```

not work in Vim?

How can I work around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is correct, and this mapping works for me in GVIM. I suspect you're using Vim in the terminal.

Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>non-alphabetic</kbd> cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens <kbd>/</kbd> is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various [proposals](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8).

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.